# Merging SVG paths of several neighboring US states

Tags: svg

I have a SVG graphic which outputs the map of the United States. Each US state is laid out as shown [here](http://www.ravelrumba.com/code/demos/us-map-raphael/demo-animated.html). The borders are drawn by means of SVG paths. Each state is represented by its own SVG path.

What I want to do is to group several neighboring states into one area, say I want California, Arizona and Nevada to appear as a single area. For that I would need to merge the paths of each of these 3 states into one path which contains all three of them.

Does anyone know of a program which does this automatically for you? Or of an approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Adobe Illustrator you can load in an SVG file as vector artwork, turn multiple paths into a single one using either the Unite Shape Mode or the Merge Pathfinder (both in the Pathfinder palette), and then export as SVG again.

Note that in your [linked-to example](http://www.ravelrumba.com/code/demos/us-map-raphael/demo-animated.html) the paths for each state do not overlap. As such, any path union performed on these paths would not change the visual appearance; there would still be a gap between the states.

If you want to obliterate the gap between the states in Illustrator, you would need to first use a Stroke on the state(s) so that the gap is covered, then choose the menu command Oʙᴊᴇᴄᴛ ▸ Pᴀᴛʜ ▸ Oᴜᴛʟɪɴᴇ Sᴛʀᴏᴋᴇ, and then Unite these along with the shapes.

If the gap is fine, and you just want to treat two (or more) states as a single object, you don't need Illustrator. Instead, place the multiple states into a group (`<g>`) and perform event handling on this group instead of each state.

This example shows two circles in a group with events and styles applied at the group level instead of the shape level:
http://phrogz.net/SVG/css-driven-styles.xhtml

**Edit**: If you don't have Adobe Illustrator, you can use the freely-available [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) program, which has its own [Path Operations](http://kalaalog.com/2007/11/01/inkscape-path-operations-basic-tutorial/).