# topojson.merge using command line API

Tags: topojson

I have a topojson file of all US states that I would like to merge into a single entity, i.e. removing common arcs.

Several answers suggest using topojson.mesh(), as is pointed out in the answer here:
[D3: Merge interior svg paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092564/d3-merge-interior-svg-paths)

However I would like to save the output topojson for reuse in the future.  So is there a way to manipulate the original file through the command line tool instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it in JS, outputting it to console in JSON format, then using terminal's topojson cmd to convert geojson back to topojson.